# React-router v6 Route composition. Is it possible to render a custom Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parse-platform, react-router, react-router-dom

For learning purposes I am trying to create a custom Route, which is protected, using React-Router v6. As many people have tried before me in Forums or here, I get this error: **Error: [ProtectedRoute] is not a  component.**

Also if someone is struggling with a non-reusable implementation can see my working code below: My problem is that I would really like it to be reusable so that I can avoid having this messy kind of code. Let me know if you have any ideas.

I personally think that it's kinda impossible because of the current V6 implementation. Maybe they will let us do it in the future. But I hope that this post will help anyway people who would like to have protected routes especially while using the Parse Platform.

**Custom Route:**

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        <AuthWrapper>
          <Component {...rest} {...props} />
        </AuthWrapper>;
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

**Wrapper using Parse Server to protect the routes if the user isn't currently logged in.**

```
const AuthWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  if (Parse.User.current() !== null) {
    let isAuthenticated = Parse.User.current().getSessionToken();
    let authCondition = isAuthenticated !== undefined;
    if (authCondition) {
      return children;
    }
  }
  return <Navigate to={"/login"} />;
};

export default AuthWrapper;
```

**Working solution without custom Route:** (ofc without `<ProtectedRoute />`)

```
<Route
  path="/book"
  element={
    <AuthWrapper>
       <BookPage />
    </AuthWrapper>
  }
/>
```

**What I would like to do instead:**

```
<ProtectedRoute
    path={'/path'}
    element={<Anything/>}
/>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`react-router-dom` v6 doesn't, and I don't suspect it ever will, support custom route components like was used in previous versions, preferring now composition. You've correctly created an `AuthWrapper` component that wraps some content, and this is the [v6 authentication example from the docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth).

But it can be improved upon. Instead of returning a single `children` node you can instead return an `Outlet` for nested `Route` components to be rendered into. This converts the `AuthWrapper` component from a wrapper component to a layout component.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthLayout = () => {
  if (Parse.User.current() !== null) {
    const isAuthenticated = Parse.User.current().getSessionToken();
    return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : null; // or loading indicator, etc...
  }
  return <Navigate to={"/login"} replace />;
};
```

This allows you to render a single `AuthLayout` component into a `Route`, and nest any number of protected routes into it.

```
<Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
  <Route path="/book" element={<BookPage />} />
  ... other protected routes ...
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix it. You missed the return in the render prop.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return (<AuthWrapper>
          <Component {...rest} {...props} />
        </AuthWrapper>);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Hey mate, it didn't! The problem is how React understands the whole thingy. Even if you get rid of everything and return a plain <Route path="/dummy"/>, the error message will still be there to haunt you . This would work in react-router v5 btw.

Comment: In RRDv6 the `Route` components don't have a `render` prop, and only `Route` or `React.Fragment` are valid children of a `Routes` component. `ProtectedRoute` is neither of these and will fail an invariant check.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by doing two things

- creating extended route object (RouteObject with my own props)
- mapping them

  - by adding wrapper with protection and custom logic
  - filtering back from ExtendedRouteObject to RouteObject

So, there is my code

```
// my service types
type Diff<T extends keyof any, U extends keyof any> = ({ [P in T]: P } & {
    [P in U]: never;
} & {
    [x: string]: never;
})[T];

export type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, keyof U>> & U;

// Overwrite is my custom type in order to override any type i need
type TExtendedRouteObject = Overwrite<
  RouteObject,
  {
    children?: TExtendedRouteObject[];
  }
> & {
  /**
   * In order to set to document.title
   */
  title: string;
};

const mapExtendedRoutes = (routeObjects: TExtendedRouteObject[]): RouteObject[] => {
  if (routeObjects.length) {
    return routeObjects.map(route => {
      if (route.children?.length) {
        return omit({
          ...route,
          element: <RouteWrapper {...route} />,
          children: mapExtendedRoutes(route.children),
        },
        ['title'],
      ) as RouteObject;
      }

      return omit({ // omit from lodash.omit
        ...route,
        element: <RouteWrapper {...route} />,
      }) as RouteObject;
    });
  }

  return [];
};

const RouteWrapper: FC<TExtendedRouteObject> = ({ element, title }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = title;
  }, [title]);

  // your auth logic goes here

  return <>{element}</>;
};

const extendedRoutes: TExtendedRouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    title: 'Homepage',
    element: <Dashboard />,
    children: [...],
  },
...
];

const routes: RouteObject[] = mapExtendedRoutes(extendedRoutes);

const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);
// then pass it to <RouterProvider router={router} />
```

Comment: Would be nice to check your Overwrite type

Comment: @tykhan no problem. Just added them